# Custom keyboard: get notified when text updates

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard, uiinputviewcontroller

Is there a method in `UIInputViewController` when the text that the custom keyboard is modifying updates? `textWillChange`/`textDidChange` only notify me about cursor movement.

Answer (score -1):

Subclass `UIInputView`. In your subclass, set up a `protocol`.

```
protocol MyCustomInputViewDidChangeDelegate {
    func customInputViewDidChange(customInputView: MyCustomInputView)
}

class MyCustomInputView: UIInputView {
    var delegate: MyCustomInputViewDidChangeDelegate?
}
```

You'll have `UIInputViewController` conform to `MyCustomInputViewDidChangeDelegate` When your custom keyboard is touched, propagate that to the delegate when appropriate by calling `delegate?.customInputViewDidChange(self)`.

Comment: -> UIInputViewController

Answer (score -1):

there are  UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification, UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification, UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
You can use

```
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.textFieldDidChanged(_:)),    name: UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification, object:self.txtAlbumName)

   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.textFieldDidChanged(_:)),    name: UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification, object:self.txtAlbumName)
  // ------------

  func textFieldDidChanged(sender:NSNotification) -> Void {

  }

  func textFieldDidChanged (sender:NSNotification) -> Void{

  }
}
```

Comment: -> UIInputViewController